# Binding a Telerik RadRibbonComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik

Could you please help to fill a telerik RadRibbonComboBox item dynamically from C# code behind by the Binding.

I already done that in the XAML page by the below instructions, and now need to do it in the code behind ?

```
<telerik:RadRibbonComboBox Name="Cmb" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="False"  Width="98" Margin="0 2 1 2" SelectionChanged="CmbSelectionChanged">   
<telerik:RadRibbonComboBoxItem Content="myContent" Tag="myTag" />
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add attribute id and onitemdatabound.

```
<telerik:RadRibbonComboBox Name="Cmb" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="False"  Width="98" Margin="0 2 1 2" SelectionChanged="CmbSelectionChanged" id="myRadRibbon" onitemdatabound="myRadRibbon">
```

After that you can make function in c# code behind (or this function will generate automatically).

```
protected void myRadRibbon(object o, RadComboBoxItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //bind
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now could you please give me an example on how to assign values to RadRibbonComboBoxItem Content and Tag properties.
 <telerik:RadRibbonComboBoxItem Content="" Tag="" />

Comment: If you define id you can call atttribute in code behind by this id. myRadRibbon.Content etc.

Comment: Please note that I'm working with _RadRibbonComboBox_ so I didn't found the _id_ and _onitemdatabound_ attributes as you describe previously !